# Nginx and SSL give me redirect loop

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying my best to turn on SSL on my website. However, I'm fairly new to the nginx config file. The code I have below, gives me a redirect loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    website.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www_website_com_final.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www_website_com.key;

    root /var/www/website.com/htdocs/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website.com/htdocs/.htpasswd;

    server_name www.website.com;

    #browse folders if no index file
    #autoindex on; 

    # serve static files directly
    #location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    #    access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    #}

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Server configuration questions should be asked on ServerFault rather than on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you have different server names in your conf file. What you conf is doing is from port 80 redirecting the request to $server_name which is "website.com" on port 443. But on port 443 your server_name is www.website.com. You can also use a wildcard server name e.g "*.website.com" in your http server block.

> ```
>   server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name website.com;
>     return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
> }
>
> server {
>     listen 443;
>     server_name www.website.com; # this needs to be changed to website.com.
>     ......
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has an issue with loop redirect and SSL

You have to enable SSL and force SSL on all page

Back-office > Preferences > General ;-)